# There are two of my 'res' and 'java' folders and one of them has a normal name and the second has '(generated)' in their names

Tags: java, android, android-studio, resources, android-resources

What's my problem and is it a problem or no?
Can I delete them?
Thanks for answers.
[my project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOU4Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Those files were already there but by building the project, they are now highlighted. You can think of them like something Android reference to, to build the project.
You can edit them but the changes will be lost, that's why when you open those files, Android show the message to not edit them. If you delete them, then it will just slow the next build because they will need to be generated again, so I'll suggest not to delete them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, You did a big favor!